# XSLT Error - A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of Date format

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am trying to work on XSLT code to read a "company" field value

XML has 2 units and the are (5000 with 3 records, 2 active 1 inactive) and (6000 with 3 records, 2 active and 1 inactive)

I have to read the "company" field value form unit 6000 only when one of the unit from 6000 "StartDate" matches a date range of unit 5000 "StartDate" field

expected XSLT output for field company value is "***2010***" for unit 6000, as it this record date matches with one of the 5000 unit record

Date range can be exactly same or it can between start and end date range period

Below code I wrote is throwing error any suggestion is helpful

XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AllRecords>
   <Records>
      <Record>
         <Items>
            <EndDate>2021-03-31T00:00:00.000</EndDate>
            <PlantDetails>
               <PlantDetailsUS>
                  <company>1000</company>
                  <Newplant>TEST1</Newplant>
               </PlantDetailsUS>
            </PlantDetails>
            <StartDate>2021-01-01T00:00:00.000</StartDate>
            <Unit>5000</Unit>
            <Status>A</Status>
         </Items>
         <Items>
            <EndDate>2020-12-31T00:00:00.000</EndDate>
            <PlantDetails>
               <PlantDetailsUS>
                  <company>1000</company>
                  <Newplant>TEST2</Newplant>
               </PlantDetailsUS>
            </PlantDetails>
            <StartDate>2020-05-01T00:00:00.000</StartDate>
            <Unit>5000</Unit>
            <Status>A</Status>
         </Items>
         <Items>
            <EndDate>2021-03-31T00:00:00.000</EndDate>
            <PlantDetails>
               <PlantDetailsUS>
                  <company>1000</company>
                  <Newplant>TEST3</Newplant>
               </PlantDetailsUS>
            </PlantDetails>
            <StartDate>2021-01-01T00:00:00.000</StartDate>
            <Unit>5000</Unit>
            <Status>I</Status>
         </Items>
         <Items>
            <EndDate>2020-12-31T00:00:00.000</EndDate>
            <PlantDetails>
               <PlantDetailsUS>
                  <company>2000</company>
                  <Newplant>TEST4</Newplant>
               </PlantDetailsUS>
            </PlantDetails>
            <StartDate>2020-01-01T00:00:00.000</StartDate>
            <Unit>6000</Unit>
            <Status>A</Status>
         </Items>
         <Items>
            <EndDate>2021-03-31T00:00:00.000</EndDate>
            <PlantDetails>
               <PlantDetailsUS>
                  <company>2010</company>
                  <Newplant>TEST5</Newplant>
               </PlantDetailsUS>
            </PlantDetails>
            <StartDate>2021-01-01T00:00:00.000</StartDate>
            <Unit>6000</Unit>
            <Status>A</Status>
         </Items>
  <Items>
            <EndDate>2021-03-31T00:00:00.000</EndDate>
            <PlantDetails>
               <PlantDetailsUS>
                  <company>2020</company>
                  <Newplant>TEST5</Newplant>
               </PlantDetailsUS>
            </PlantDetails>
            <StartDate>2021-01-01T00:00:00.000</StartDate>
            <Unit>6000</Unit>
            <Status>I</Status>
         </Items>
      </Record>
   </Records>
</AllRecords>
```

xslt code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0">
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <Root>
         <xsl:apply-templates />
      </Root>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="AllRecords/Records/Record">
      <xsl:if test="Record/Items[unit=5000]/unit =5000 or Record/Items[unit=6000]/unit = 6000">
         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="Record/Items[unit=5000][Status='A']">
               <xsl:for-each select="Record/Items[unit='5000'][Status='A']">
                  <row>
                     <xsl:if test="substring(//Items[Status = 'A' and unit=5000]/StartDate,1,10) &gt;= substring(//Items[Status = 'A' and ( unit=6000) ]/StartDate,1,10)">
                        &gt;
                        <xsl:value-of select="//company" />
                     </xsl:if>
                  </row>
               </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:when>
         </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Is the a record with value "2010" in the sample data of your question?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
substring(//Items[Status = 'A' and unit=5000]/StartDate,1,10)
```

by

```
//Items[Status = 'A' and unit=5000]/StartDate ! substring(., 1, 10)
```

in 3.0, or by

```
for $x in //Items[Status = 'A' and unit=5000]/StartDate return substring(., 1, 10)
```

or

```
//Items[Status = 'A' and unit=5000]/StartDate / substring(., 1, 10)
```

in 2.0

substring(), and many other such functions, expect a single string as the operand, and if you want to apply the function to many strings, you have to do so explicitly.

Comment: Thank you, i tried but no luck, substring is not an issue, issue is looping through multiple records and get the exact value